# Neural network from scratch tutorial on towards data science.com doesn't work because of indentation error

Tags: python

```
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
             self.input = x
             self.weights1= np.random.rand(self.input.shape[1],4)
            self.weights2 = np.random.rand(4,1)
            self.y = y
            self.output=np.zeros(y.shape)
        
    def feedfoward(self):
            self.layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.input, self.weights1))
            self.output = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights2))
    
    def backprop(self):
        #use chain rule to find derivative of the loss function, with respect to weights2  and weights1.
            d_weights2= np.dot(self.layer1.T, (2*(self.y-self.output)*sigmoid_derivative(self.output)))
            d_weights1= np.dot(self.input.T, (np.dot(2*(self.y-self.output)*sigmoid_derivative(self.output),self.weights2.T)*sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1)))
    #update the weights with the derivative(slope) of the loss function
             self.weights1 += d_weights1
             self.weights2 += d_weights2
```

I'm on mobile if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. I've corrected the indentation errors at the **3rd**, **4th**, **18th**, and **19th** lines. Always make sure that the statements are all equally indented.

```
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.input = x
        self.weights1= np.random.rand(self.input.shape[1],4)
        self.weights2 = np.random.rand(4,1)
        self.y = y
        self.output=np.zeros(y.shape)
    
    def feedfoward(self):
        self.layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.input, self.weights1))
        self.output = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights2))
    
    def backprop(self):
        #use chain rule to find derivative of the loss function, with respect to weights2  and weights1.
        d_weights2= np.dot(self.layer1.T, (2*(self.y-self.output)*sigmoid_derivative(self.output)))
        d_weights1= np.dot(self.input.T, (np.dot(2*(self.y-self.output)*sigmoid_derivative(self.output),self.weights2.T)*sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1)))
        #update the weights with the derivative(slope) of the loss function
        self.weights1 += d_weights1
        self.weights2 += d_weights2
```